# Coffeescript : setInterval, clearInterval and anonymous function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, scope, closures, setinterval

I use setInterval() into an anonymous function and I want to use clearInterval() in another anonymous function. I'm using socket.io and I need to have intervalID for each socket, so I can't use global variable.

I can clearInterval when clearLoops() is fired into the setInterval loop, but it doesn't work in my other socket events.

```
io.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  intervalID = -1

  clearLoops = ->
     if intervalID != -1
       clearInterval intervalID
       intervalID = -1

  socket.on 'first:action', (data, callback) ->
    myArray = data
    setTimeout(->
      intervalID = setInterval(->
        arrLength = myArray.length
        if arrLength is 0
          clearLoops()
        while i < arrLength
          if myArray[i].score >= MAX_SCORE
            myArray.splice i, 1
            i--
            arrLength--
          i++
      , 300)
    , 3000)


  socket.on 'second:action', ->
    clearLoops()


  socket.on 'disconnect', ->
    clearLoops()
```

Comment: This looks like a scoping issue. I suspect there's an "undefined is not a function" error in your browser console because `clearLoops` isn't in scope where you're trying to call it.

Comment: I can call `clearLoops`, but `intervalID` is always equals to `-1` except when it called into the `setInterval` loop. I think it's a scoping issue too, maybe anonymous functions of socket.io are guilty ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not syntactically valid. Line 9 is missing a comma between parameters:

```
 socket.on 'first:action' (data, callback) ->
```

should be

```
 socket.on 'first:action', (data, callback) ->
```

Hint: http://coffeescript.org's "Try CoffeeScript" feature has  a built-in syntax checker which you can use to double-check your code snippets when they're not working as expected.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bad code review before posting. I check my file, there is comma.
I edited the post.